# do we need AWS SCT in order to use DMS for GCP Cloud SQL to AWS Aurora MySQL data migration?

Tags: aws-dms, amazon-aurora

As per the AWS DMS documentation it mentioned that for heterogeneous database migration it needs SCT for schema conversion and with that it generated test_dbo schema in target aurora mysql database where "test" is the schema in the source database which is GCP cloud sql server. But, after running the DMS replication task, source data copied to "dbo" schema instead of "test_dbo". So, here my question is, does DMS use SCT or not? If SCT required how to configure?